# Javascript fetch sending HTML and URL strings in an HTTP request

Tags: javascript, json, http-headers, fetch

I need to send both a URL and HTML string in a `fetch` post request. But I am not sure the proper way to do this. The backend is flexible in how it receives the data, I just don't know whether there is a proper way to do this or whether it doesn't matter and is up to the developer. I have the following HTML and URL:

```js
const myUrl = "https://www.example.com/";
const myHtml = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Should I send as HTML with a custom header:

```js
fetch("/api", {
  method: "post",
  mode: "no-cors",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/html",
    myUrl,
  },
  body: myHtml,
});
```

Or JSON:

```js
fetch("/api", {
  method: "post",
  mode: "no-cors",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: { myUrl, myHtml },
});
```

Or does it not matter?

Comment: `document.documentElement.innerHTML` isn’t full HTML; I’d go with `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document, "text/html")` instead — this would be valid `text/html`. If this HTML is a string, I’d simply go with JSON then.